# ¿Como converir este código a su lenguaje original?

Tags: php, javascript, html, desofuscación

Tengo el siguiente **código** de una plantilla que descargué, pero necesito traducir este y otro **código** mas para poder editar algunos puntos importantes de la página, agradecería mucho su ayuda con la **traducción** o si me pueden referenciar alguna página para realizar este proceso.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var _0x7193=[
"\x24\x28\x36\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x59\x20\x41\x27\x29\x2E\x79\x28\x22\x3C\x34\x20\x42\x3D\x27\x43\x2D\x47\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x31\x31\x20\x41\x27\x29\x2E\x79\x28\x22\x3C\x34\x20\x42\x3D\x27\x43\x2D\x47\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x22\x2E\x71\x2D\x38\x20\x70\x20\x56\x3A\x54\x2D\x52\x28\x31\x29\x22\x29\x2E\x53\x28\x27\x57\x27\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x36\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x20\x6A\x3D\x24\x28\x27\x23\x6A\x27\x29\x3B\x38\x3D\x24\x28\x27\x2E\x71\x2D\x38\x20\x70\x27\x29\x3B\x58\x3D\x38\x2E\x51\x28\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x6A\x29\x2E\x31\x30\x28\x27\x5A\x27\x2C\x36\x28\x65\x29\x7B\x65\x2E\x31\x32\x28\x29\x3B\x38\x2E\x4F\x28\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x24\x28\x67\x29\x2E\x4A\x28\x36\x28\x29\x7B\x35\x20\x77\x3D\x24\x28\x67\x29\x2E\x50\x28\x29\x3B\x62\x28\x77\x3E\x4B\x26\x26\x38\x2E\x4E\x28\x27\x3A\x4D\x27\x29\x29\x7B\x38\x2E\x4C\x28\x27\x6D\x27\x29\x7D\x7D\x29\x7D\x29\x3B\x36\x20\x6C\x28\x33\x2C\x37\x29\x7B\x62\x28\x33\x2E\x64\x28\x22\x3C\x22\x29\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x7B\x35\x20\x73\x3D\x33\x2E\x55\x28\x22\x3C\x22\x29\x3B\x31\x38\x28\x35\x20\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x73\x2E\x39\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x62\x28\x73\x5B\x69\x5D\x2E\x64\x28\x22\x3E\x22\x29\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x7B\x73\x5B\x69\x5D\x3D\x73\x5B\x69\x5D\x2E\x6E\x28\x73\x5B\x69\x5D\x2E\x64\x28\x22\x3E\x22\x29\x2B\x31\x2C\x73\x5B\x69\x5D\x2E\x39\x29\x7D\x7D\x33\x3D\x73\x2E\x31\x6C\x28\x22\x22\x29\x7D\x37\x3D\x28\x37\x3C\x33\x2E\x39\x2D\x31\x29\x3F\x37\x3A\x33\x2E\x39\x2D\x32\x3B\x31\x6D\x28\x33\x2E\x31\x6B\x28\x37\x2D\x31\x29\x21\x3D\x27\x20\x27\x26\x26\x33\x2E\x64\x28\x27\x20\x27\x2C\x37\x29\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x37\x2B\x2B\x3B\x33\x3D\x33\x2E\x6E\x28\x30\x2C\x37\x2D\x31\x29\x3B\x31\x6E\x20\x33\x2B\x27\x2E\x2E\x2E\x27\x7D\x36\x20\x31\x6F\x28\x6F\x29\x7B\x35\x20\x34\x3D\x44\x2E\x31\x33\x28\x6F\x29\x3B\x35\x20\x66\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x35\x20\x63\x3D\x34\x2E\x31\x70\x28\x22\x63\x22\x29\x3B\x35\x20\x68\x3D\x31\x6A\x3B\x62\x28\x31\x68\x3D\x3D\x22\x31\x69\x22\x29\x7B\x62\x28\x63\x2E\x39\x3E\x3D\x31\x29\x7B\x66\x3D\x27\x3C\x6B\x20\x6D\x3D\x22\x31\x39\x3A\x31\x37\x3B\x20\x31\x36\x3A\x72\x20\x31\x34\x20\x31\x35\x20\x72\x3B\x22\x3E\x3C\x63\x20\x74\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x63\x5B\x30\x5D\x2E\x74\x2B\x27\x22\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6B\x3E\x27\x3B\x68\x3D\x31\x61\x7D\x7D\x35\x20\x45\x3D\x66\x2B\x27\x3C\x34\x3E\x27\x2B\x6C\x28\x34\x2E\x78\x2C\x68\x29\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x34\x3E\x27\x3B\x34\x2E\x78\x3D\x45\x7D\x24\x28\x44\x29\x2E\x31\x62\x28\x36\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x7A\x27\x29\x2E\x31\x67\x28\x22\x3C\x61\x20\x46\x3D\x27\x76\x3A\x2F\x2F\x75\x2E\x48\x2E\x49\x2F\x27\x3E\x20\x31\x66\x20\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x31\x65\x28\x36\x28\x29\x7B\x62\x28\x21\x24\x28\x22\x23\x7A\x3A\x31\x63\x22\x29\x2E\x39\x29\x67\x2E\x31\x64\x2E\x46\x3D\x22\x76\x3A\x2F\x2F\x75\x2E\x48\x2E\x49\x2F\x22\x7D\x2C\x31\x71\x29\x7D\x29\x3B",
"\x7C",
"\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74",
"\x7C\x7C\x7C\x73\x74\x72\x78\x7C\x64\x69\x76\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x63\x68\x6F\x70\x7C\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x7C\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7C\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66\x7C\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x74\x61\x67\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x7C\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x7C\x7C\x70\x75\x6C\x6C\x7C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x7C\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x48\x74\x6D\x6C\x54\x61\x67\x7C\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x7C\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x70\x49\x44\x7C\x75\x6C\x7C\x6E\x61\x76\x7C\x30\x70\x78\x7C\x7C\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x77\x77\x77\x7C\x68\x74\x74\x70\x7C\x7C\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x7C\x77\x72\x61\x70\x7C\x6D\x79\x63\x72\x65\x64\x69\x74\x7C\x68\x32\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x77\x69\x64\x67\x65\x74\x7C\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x7C\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x79\x61\x72\x64\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x72\x65\x73\x69\x7A\x65\x7C\x33\x32\x30\x7C\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x41\x74\x74\x72\x7C\x68\x69\x64\x64\x65\x6E\x7C\x69\x73\x7C\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x54\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65\x7C\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x7C\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x7C\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x6E\x74\x68\x7C\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74\x7C\x6C\x69\x7C\x68\x69\x67\x68\x6C\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x6D\x65\x6E\x75\x48\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x73\x69\x64\x65\x62\x61\x72\x7C\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B\x7C\x6F\x6E\x7C\x6C\x6F\x77\x65\x72\x62\x61\x72\x7C\x70\x72\x65\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x44\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64\x7C\x31\x30\x70\x78\x7C\x35\x70\x78\x7C\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x7C\x66\x6F\x72\x7C\x66\x6C\x6F\x61\x74\x7C\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x5F\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x7C\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x65\x7C\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x73\x65\x74\x49\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x76\x61\x6C\x7C\x54\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x79\x61\x72\x64\x7C\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x7C\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x6E\x61\x69\x6C\x5F\x6D\x6F\x64\x65\x7C\x79\x65\x73\x7C\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x5F\x6E\x6F\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x63\x68\x61\x72\x41\x74\x7C\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E\x7C\x77\x68\x69\x6C\x65\x7C\x72\x65\x74\x75\x72\x6E\x7C\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x53\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x41\x6E\x64\x54\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x7C\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65\x7C\x33\x30\x30\x30",
"",
"\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x5C\x62","\x67","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65"
];
eval(function(_0xd323x1,_0xd323x2,_0xd323x3,_0xd323x4,_0xd323x5,_0xd323x6){
  _0xd323x5=function(_0xd323x3){ 
     return (_0xd323x3<_0xd323x2?_0x7193[4]:_0xd323x5(parseInt(_0xd323x3/_0xd323x2)))+((_0xd323x3=_0xd323x3%_0xd323x2)>35?String[_0x7193[5]](_0xd323x3+29):_0xd323x3.toString(36))};

  while(_0xd323x3--){
    if(_0xd323x4[_0xd323x3]){
      _0xd323x1=_0xd323x1[_0x7193[8]]( new RegExp(_0x7193[6]+_0xd323x5(_0xd323x3)+_0x7193[6],_0x7193[7]),_0xd323x4[_0xd323x3])
    }
  };
  return _0xd323x1;
}(_0x7193[0],62,89,_0x7193[3][_0x7193[2]](_0x7193[1])));
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Al agregar **console.log(_0x7193)** me aparece lo siguiente y no se como **desofuscar** el "eval"

```
Array [ "$(6(){$('.Y A').y(\"<4 B='C-G'></4>\");$('.11 A').y(\"<4 B='C-G'></4>\");$(\".q-8 p V:T-R(1)\").S('W')});$(6(){5 j=$('#j');8=$('.q-8 p');X=8.Q();$(j).10('Z',6(e){e.12();8.O()});$(g).J(6(){5 w=$(g).P();b(w>K&&8.N(':M')){8.L('m')}})});6 l(3,7){b(3.d(\"<\")!=-1){5 s=3.U(\"<\");18(5 i=0;i<s.9;i++){b(s[i].d(\">\")!=-1){s[i]=s[i].n(s[i].d(\">\")+1,s[i].9)}}3=s.1l(\"\")}7=(7<3.9-1)?7:3.9-2;1m(3.1k(7-1)!=' '&&3.d(' ',7)!=-1)7++;3=3.n(0,7-1);1n 3+'...'}6 1o(o){5 4=D.13(o);5 f=\"\";5 c=4.1p(\"c\");5 h=1j;b(1h==\"1i\"){b(c.9>=1){f='<k m=\"19:17; 16:r 14 15 r;\"><c t=\"'+c[0].t+'\"/></k>';h=1a}}5 E=f+'<4>'+l(4.x,h)+'</4>';4.x=E}$(D).1b(6(){$('#z').1g(\"<a F='v://u.H.I/'> 1f </a>\");1e(6(){b(!$(\"#z:1c\").9)g.1d.F=\"v://u.H.I/\"},1q)});", "|", "split", "|||strx|div|var|function|chop|menu|length||if|img|indexOf||imgtag|window|summ||pull|span|removeHtmlTag|style|substring|pID|ul|nav|0px||src|www|http||innerHTML|wrap|mycredit|h2|class|widget|document|summary|href|title|templatesyard|com|resize|320|removeAttr|hidden|is|slideToggle|width|height|child|addClass|nth|split|li|highlight|menuHeight|sidebar|click|on|lowerbar|preventDefault|getElementById|10px|5px|padding|left|for|float|summary_img|ready|visible|location|setInterval|Templatesyard|html|thumbnail_mode|yes|summary_noimg|charAt|join|while|return|createSummaryAndThumb|getElementsByTagName|3000", "", "fromCharCode", "\\b", "g", "replace" ]
```

Comment: Investiga el tema de la desofuscación de codigo. Busca herramientas que te permitan hacerlo y si tienes problemas **concretos** o errores, pregunta aqui siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Yo empezaría quitando desde el `eval()` en adelante y hacienda un `console.log(_0x7193)`. Dependiendo de lo que viera, ya me metería en desofuscar el `eval` o no. Y siempre en una máquina virtual, porque a mí me huele a malware de lejos.

Comment: Creo que falta una parte, pero si reemplazas el eval por console.log, o alert, deberías ver el código normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estás evaluando una función cuya impronta es:

```
function(_0xd323x1,_0xd323x2,_0xd323x3,_0xd323x4,_0xd323x5,_0xd323x6)
```

Pero se autoinvoca pasándole `_0xd323x2 = 62` y `_0xd323x3 = 89` por lo cual puedes omitir esos parámetros y declararlos dentro de la función. Además, considerando que los parámetros `_0xd323x5` y `_0xd323x6` no se le pasan ni se usan en la función, puedes quitarlos.

El primer parámetro es el código que desencriptaste como primer elemento:

```
$(6(){$('.Y A').y(\"<4 B='C-G'>\");$('.11 A').y(\"<4 B='C-G'>\");$(\".q-8 p V:T-R(1)\").S('W')});$(6(){5 j=$('#j');8=$('.q-8 p');X=8.Q();$(j).10('Z',6(e){e.12();8.O()});$(g).J(6(){5 w=$(g).P();b(w>K&&8.N(':M')){8.L('m')}})});6 l(3,7){b(3.d(\"<\")!=-1){5 s=3.U(\"<\");18(5 i=0;i\")!=-1){s[i]=s[i].n(s[i].d(\">\")+1,s[i].9)}}3=s.1l(\"\")}7=(7<3.9-1)?7:3.9-2;1m(3.1k(7-1)!=' '&&3.d(' ',7)!=-1)7++;3=3.n(0,7-1);1n 3+'...'}6 1o(o){5 4=D.13(o);5 f=\"\";5 c=4.1p(\"c\");5 h=1j;b(1h==\"1i\"){b(c.9>=1){f='';h=1a}}5 E=f+'<4>'+l(4.x,h)+'';4.x=E}$(D).1b(6(){$('#z').1g(\" 1f \");1e(6(){b(!$(\"#z:1c\").9)g.1d.F=\"v://u.H.I/\"},1q)});
```

El segundo parámetro es un array que resulta al explotar `|||strx|div|var|function|chop|menu|length...` usando `|` como separador.

La función recorre este array mediante un while que parte en 89 y va decreciendo hasta el cero. Cada índice del while es transformado a uno o dos caracteres. Digamos que esta transformación devuelve un `numero_convertido`.

Luego reemplaza en el primer parámetro (el código ofuscado), el `numero_convertido` con el elemento correspondiente del array. Por ejemplo, cuando el contador es 6 (el número convertido también es 6) reemplaza 6 por el sexto elemento del array, que es `function`:

```
codigo_encriptado = codigo_encriptado.replace(/\b6\b/g,'function');
```

Cuando el contador es 11, el número convertido es la letra b, la cual reemplaza por el elemento 11 del array, que es `if`

```
codigo_encriptado = codigo_encriptado.replace(/\bb\b/g,'if');
```

Digamos que todo ocurre dentro de una función llamada  `ejecutar`:

```
function ejecutar(codigo_encriptado, array_reemplazo) {
    var contador = 89;
    var convertir_numero = function (numero) {
        return (numero < 62 ? "" : convertir_numero(parseInt(numero / 62))) + ((numero = numero % 62) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(numero + 29) :
            numero.toString(36))
    };
    while (contador--) {

        var numero_convertido = convertir_numero(contador),
            regex = "\b" + numero_convertido + "\b";

        if (array_reemplazo[contador]) {
            codigo_encriptado = codigo_encriptado.replace(new RegExp(regex, "g"), array_reemplazo[contador]);

        }
    }


    return codigo_encriptado;
};
```

Luego llamas a la función  `ejecutar` como:

```
ejecutar(
    "$(6(){$('.Y A').y(\"<4 B='C-G'>\");$('.11 A').y(\"<4 B='C-G'>\");$(\".q-8 p V:T-R(1)\").S('W')});$(6(){5 j=$('#j');8=$('.q-8 p');X=8.Q();$(j).10('Z',6(e){e.12();8.O()});$(g).J(6(){5 w=$(g).P();b(w>K&&8.N(':M')){8.L('m')}})});6 l(3,7){b(3.d(\"<\")!=-1){5 s=3.U(\"<\");18(5 i=0;i\")!=-1){s[i]=s[i].n(s[i].d(\">\")+1,s[i].9)}}3=s.1l(\"\")}7=(7<3.9-1)?7:3.9-2;1m(3.1k(7-1)!=' '&&3.d(' ',7)!=-1)7++;3=3.n(0,7-1);1n 3+'...'}6 1o(o){5 4=D.13(o);5 f=\"\";5 c=4.1p(\"c\");5 h=1j;b(1h==\"1i\"){b(c.9>=1){f='';h=1a}}5 E=f+'<4>'+l(4.x,h)+'';4.x=E}$(D).1b(6(){$('#z').1g(\" 1f \");1e(6(){b(!$(\"#z:1c\").9)g.1d.F=\"v://u.H.I/\"},1q)});", [
        "", "", "", "strx", "div", "var", "function", "chop", "menu", "length", "", "if", "img", "indexOf", "", "imgtag", "window", "summ", "", "pull", "span", "removeHtmlTag",
        "style", "substring", "pID", "ul", "nav", "0px", "", "src", "www", "http", "", "innerHTML", "wrap", "mycredit", "h2", "class", "widget", "document", "summary", "href", "title",
        "templatesyard", "com", "resize", "320", "removeAttr", "hidden", "is", "slideToggle", "width", "height", "child", "addClass", "nth", "split", "li", "highlight", "menuHeight",
        "sidebar", "click", "on", "lowerbar", "preventDefault", "getElementById", "10px", "5px", "padding", "left", "for", "float", "summary_img", "ready", "visible", "location",
        "setInterval", "Templatesyard", "html", "thumbnail_mode", "yes", "summary_noimg", "charAt", "join", "while", "return", "createSummaryAndThumb", "getElementsByTagName", "3000"
    ]);
```

La salida es el primer parámetro desencriptado. Una cadena de texto que al pasar por `eval` se ejecuta.

Aplicando todos los reemplazos:

```js
var codigo_encriptado="$(6(){$('.Y A').y(\"<4 B='C-G'>\");$('.11 A').y(\"<4 B='C-G'>\");$(\".q-8 p V:T-R(1)\").S('W')});$(6(){5 j=$('#j');8=$('.q-8 p');X=8.Q();$(j).10('Z',6(e){e.12();8.O()});$(g).J(6(){5 w=$(g).P();b(w>K&&8.N(':M')){8.L('m')}})});6 l(3,7){b(3.d(\"<\")!=-1){5 s=3.U(\"<\");18(5 i=0;i\")!=-1){s[i]=s[i].n(s[i].d(\">\")+1,s[i].9)}}3=s.1l(\"\")}7=(7<3.9-1)?7:3.9-2;1m(3.1k(7-1)!=' '&&3.d(' ',7)!=-1)7++;3=3.n(0,7-1);1n 3+'...'}6 1o(o){5 4=D.13(o);5 f=\"\";5 c=4.1p(\"c\");5 h=1j;b(1h==\"1i\"){b(c.9>=1){f='';h=1a}}5 E=f+'<4>'+l(4.x,h)+'';4.x=E}$(D).1b(6(){$('#z').1g(\" 1f \");1e(6(){b(!$(\"#z:1c\").9)g.1d.F=\"v://u.H.I/\"},1q)});";

var desofuscado = codigo_encriptado.replace(/\b1q\b/g, '3000')
  .replace(/\b1p\b/g, 'getElementsByTagName')
  .replace(/\b1o\b/g, 'createSummaryAndThumb')
  .replace(/\b1n\b/g, 'return')
  .replace(/\b1m\b/g, 'while')
  .replace(/\b1l\b/g, 'join')
  .replace(/\b1k\b/g, 'charAt')
  .replace(/\b1j\b/g, 'summary_noimg')
  .replace(/\b1i\b/g, 'yes')
  .replace(/\b1h\b/g, 'thumbnail_mode')
  .replace(/\b1g\b/g, 'html')
  .replace(/\b1f\b/g, 'Templatesyard')
  .replace(/\b1e\b/g, 'setInterval')
  .replace(/\b1d\b/g, 'location')
  .replace(/\b1c\b/g, 'visible')
  .replace(/\b1b\b/g, 'ready')
  .replace(/\b1a\b/g, 'summary_img')
  .replace(/\b19\b/g, 'float')
  .replace(/\b18\b/g, 'for')
  .replace(/\b17\b/g, 'left')
  .replace(/\b16\b/g, 'padding')
  .replace(/\b15\b/g, '5px')
  .replace(/\b14\b/g, '10px')
  .replace(/\b13\b/g, 'getElementById')
  .replace(/\b12\b/g, 'preventDefault')
  .replace(/\b11\b/g, 'lowerbar')
  .replace(/\b10\b/g, 'on')
  .replace(/\bZ\b/g, 'click')
  .replace(/\bY\b/g, 'sidebar')
  .replace(/\bX\b/g, 'menuHeight')
  .replace(/\bW\b/g, 'highlight')
  .replace(/\bV\b/g, 'li')
  .replace(/\bU\b/g, 'split')
  .replace(/\bT\b/g, 'nth')
  .replace(/\bS\b/g, 'addClass')
  .replace(/\bR\b/g, 'child')
  .replace(/\bQ\b/g, 'height')
  .replace(/\bP\b/g, 'width')
  .replace(/\bO\b/g, 'slideToggle')
  .replace(/\bN\b/g, 'is')
  .replace(/\bM\b/g, 'hidden')
  .replace(/\bL\b/g, 'removeAttr')
  .replace(/\bK\b/g, '320')
  .replace(/\bJ\b/g, 'resize')
  .replace(/\bI\b/g, 'com')
  .replace(/\bH\b/g, 'templatesyard')
  .replace(/\bG\b/g, 'title')
  .replace(/\bF\b/g, 'href')
  .replace(/\bE\b/g, 'summary')
  .replace(/\bD\b/g, 'document')
  .replace(/\bC\b/g, 'widget')
  .replace(/\bB\b/g, 'class')
  .replace(/\bA\b/g, 'h2')
  .replace(/\bz\b/g, 'mycredit')
  .replace(/\by\b/g, 'wrap')
  .replace(/\bx\b/g, 'innerHTML')
  .replace(/\bv\b/g, 'http')
  .replace(/\bu\b/g, 'www')
  .replace(/\bt\b/g, 'src')
  .replace(/\br\b/g, '0px')
  .replace(/\bq\b/g, 'nav')
  .replace(/\bp\b/g, 'ul')
  .replace(/\bo\b/g, 'pID')
  .replace(/\bn\b/g, 'substring')
  .replace(/\bm\b/g, 'style')
  .replace(/\bl\b/g, 'removeHtmlTag')
  .replace(/\bk\b/g, 'span')
  .replace(/\bj\b/g, 'pull')
  .replace(/\bh\b/g, 'summ')
  .replace(/\bg\b/g, 'window')
  .replace(/\bf\b/g, 'imgtag')
  .replace(/\bd\b/g, 'indexOf')
  .replace(/\bc\b/g, 'img')
  .replace(/\bb\b/g, 'if')
  .replace(/\b9\b/g, 'length')
  .replace(/\b8\b/g, 'menu')
  .replace(/\b7\b/g, 'chop')
  .replace(/\b6\b/g, 'function')
  .replace(/\b5\b/g, 'var')
  .replace(/\b4\b/g, 'div')
  .replace(/\b3\b/g, 'strx');
 console.log(desofuscado);
```

Se obtiene que el código que se ejecuta en el eval es (más o menos, porque tuve que indentarlo a mano):

```
$(function () {
    $('.sidebar h2').wrap("<div class='widget-title'>");
    $('.lowerbar h2').wrap("<div class='widget-title'>");
    $(".nav-menu ul li:nth-child(1)").addClass('highlight')
});
$(function () {
    var pull = $('#pull');
    menu = $('.nav-menu ul');
    menuHeight = menu.height();
    $(pull).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var w = $(window).width();
        if (w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});

function removeHtmlTag(strx, chop) {
    if (strx.indexOf("<") != -1) {
        var s = strx.split("<");
        for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">") + 1, s[i].length)
        }
    }
    strx = s.join("")

    chop = (chop < strx.length - 1) ? chop : strx.length - 2;
    while (strx.charAt(chop - 1) != ' ' && strx.indexOf(' ', chop) != -1) {
        chop++;
    }
    strx = strx.substring(0, chop - 1);
    return strx + '...'
}

function createSummaryAndThumb(pID) {
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if (thumbnail_mode == "yes") {
        if (img.length >= 1) {
            imgtag = '';
            summ = summary_img
        }
    }
    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML, summ) + '';
    div.innerHTML = summary
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mycredit').html(" Templatesyard ");
    setInterval(function () {
        if (!$("#mycredit:visible").length) {
            window.location.href = "http://www.templatesyard.com/";
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

Básicamente, manipular el DOM y asegurarse de que el div `#mycredit` sea visible. En caso contrario, te manda a http://www.templatesyard.com/

En conclusión, lo que hace ese código es asegurarse de que cuando uses una de sus plantillas esté visible su sitio en los créditos. **No es un código malicioso**, sino simplemente ofuscado para que no sea tan fácil quitar u ocultar la etiqueta que linkea a TemplatesYard.

Comment: amenadiel yo quisiera saber como hacer exactamente lo contrario es decir, tengo un cliente que es un instituto educativo que quiere dar una plantilla para que sus alumnos creen un blog pero no editen ciertas partes de la plantilla y me piden que añada este tipo de protección pero no se como hacerlo. tienes alguna idea?

Comment: busca un uglifier online y mete tu código ahí